# Dynamically choose Oracle.DataAccess version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oracle, reference

Is there a way to build our web application to dynamically choose Oracle version? I think you can use binding redirect, but I am not sure if it requires the versions to be in the GAC (our assemblies are not GAC'ed)

We need to use Oracle.DataAccess v. 2.102.4.0 on 32 bit systems and v. 2.112.1.0 on 64 bit systems.

I would really appreciate an example of how to set up the app references/web.config to dynamically choose this.

Comment: Did you set 'specific version' to true?

Comment: Mine is set to specific false and it returns errors when versions are not the same or lower than the one I used.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the following solution is not what you're asking for...
But you could rethink the approach to the problem, **if you're sure that you just need to switch the oracle assembly version**.

If this setting will not change after deployment you could modify `web.config` at *install time* using a simple script (e.g. in python): *load the file and replace the correct node* (do it in any language you prefer for this kind of admin tasks).

Regards,
Giacomo